# Rust application exiting with error code: (exit code: 0xc0000005, STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION)

Tags: rust

Basically, when following the book Rust in Action: System's Programming Concepts And Techniques, The material implements a custom allocator (which basically calls System allocator, but prints out the allocation time, etc). I thought I could modify the custom allocator to write the allocation time to a file so I could do some EDA with Pandas, but this seems to fail spectacularly as I have now gotten the above mentioned error.

```
#[global_allocator]
static ALLOCATOR: ReportingAllocator = ReportingAllocator;
struct ReportingAllocator;

unsafe impl GlobalAlloc for ReportingAllocator{
    unsafe fn alloc(&self, layout : Layout) -> *mut u8{
        let start = Instant::now();
        let ptr = System.alloc(layout);
        let end = Instant::now();
        let time_taken = end - start;
        let bytes_requested = layout.size();
        //TODO: convert data to strings and pass to func
        let str_bytes = format!("{}", bytes_requested);
        let str_time = format!("{}", time_taken.as_nanos());
        log_data(str_bytes, str_time);
        // eprintln!("{}\t{}", bytes_requested, time_taken.as_nanos());
        return ptr;
    }

    unsafe fn dealloc(&self, ptr: *mut u8, layout: Layout) -> (){
        System.dealloc(ptr, layout);
    }
}
```

The function log data is as follows:

```
fn log_data(mem: String, time: String){
    let mut test = match File::options().append(true).open("src/log_data.csv"){
        Ok(var) => var,
        Err(_) => panic!("File could not be opened in read only mode!")
    };
    writeln!(&mut test, "{}, {}", mem, time).expect("Unsuccessful Write");
}
```

The file was created in the main function.

So now I don't know how to still write to the file, and avoid the error

Comment: `format` allocates. That can't be good from within the `#[global_allocator]`

Comment: I think that the problem is that, to create a handle to the file opened, Rust has to allocate, which in turn triggers your allocator which tries to use that handle (that is still being created) to log the allocation.

Comment: @jthulhu it's not the `File`, that's just a wrapper around an fd (or HANDLE on windows). It's the `format!` which needs to allocat, triggering a recursive call to the allocator which (I assume) ultimately overflows the stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`format!()` creates a new `String`, which means allocating. So you recursively call the allocator until you get a stack overflow.

There are multiple ways to solve this: use a preallocated buffer and make sure to not allocate, allocate using the system allocator directly, calling the libc allocator...

You also must not panic inside the allocator, because [it's UB if the allocator unwinds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.GlobalAlloc.html#safety). You must also not print inside, because the runtime may allocate at startup, before printing is ready.

In general, custom allocators needs to be extremely cautious with the code they call. I don't think you can use anything in `std` or `alloc` safely, only `core` or call `libc` directly.

Here's an example of how to do it safely using `libc` and stack buffer instead of allocating APIs:

```rust
unsafe impl GlobalAlloc for ReportingAllocator {
    unsafe fn alloc(&self, layout: Layout) -> *mut u8 {
        let start = Instant::now();
        let ptr = System.alloc(layout);
        let end = Instant::now();
        let time_taken = end - start;
        let time_taken = time_taken.as_nanos();
        let mut io_buffer = [0u8; 100];
        let mut io_buffer_tmp = &mut io_buffer[..];
        let bytes_requested = layout.size();
        // Do not `unwrap()` here!
        _ = writeln!(io_buffer_tmp, "{}, {}", time_taken, bytes_requested);
        let spare_len = io_buffer_tmp.len();
        let written_len = io_buffer.len() - spare_len;
        let io_buffer = &io_buffer[..written_len];

        let file = libc::fopen(
            b"src/log_data.csv\0".as_ptr().cast::<libc::c_char>(),
            "a\0".as_ptr().cast::<libc::c_char>(),
        );
        if !file.is_null() {
            libc::fwrite(
                io_buffer.as_ptr().cast::<libc::c_void>(),
                std::mem::size_of::<u8>(),
                io_buffer.len(),
                file,
            );
            libc::fclose(file);
        }

        return ptr;
    }

    unsafe fn dealloc(&self, ptr: *mut u8, layout: Layout) -> () {
        System.dealloc(ptr, layout);
    }
}
```

Of course, a more efficient approach will be to cache the file handle, and an even more efficient approach will be to store the data in memory and only once a while write it in a bulk to the file.

Comment: It's not explicitly mentioned, but a stack buffer can also work if you known the work is bounded. Here `as_nanos` returns a u128, and `usize` is *technically* unbounded but I'm sure there are ways to assert that it's below some value (or you can just assume it is, for an ad-hoc debugging allocator that seems fine). Decimalisation is 5 characters per 16 bytes, so a u128 will always fit in a 40 bytes stack buffer (there's actually one to spare), and a u64 in 20.

Comment: I'm new to rust, so could you please give a little demonstration of what you mean? Thank you. While I understand the concept, the demonstration would go a long way

Comment: @Nnanna Updated with more explanations and an example.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I really appreciate your example!